# Best way to exeute various tests in protractor for various login id's

Tags: protractor

I have to test application using protractor for various different types of users. userid determines the type of user( Admin or partner or user). For all users i need to test the application for all major functionality. Here is what i want to do

**Login User 1** > execute test1, test 2, test 3 .... **Logout**

**Login user 2** > execute test1, test 2, test 3 .... **Logout**

**Login User 3** > execute test1, test 2, test 3 .... **Logout**

**Login User 4** > execute test1, test 2, test 3 .... **Logout**

I want to create a test framework to cover the scenario. I would appreciate inputs on best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a couple of ways. There are pro's and con's to each.

The first way is to just loop over the list of users.

```
describe('your suite', () => {
  for (let user of users) {
    describe('test for user: ' + user.username, () => {
      beforeAll(() => { login(user) });

      it('should do a test', () => { 
        // test code with user
      });

      it('should do another test', () => { 
        // test code with user
      });

      afterAll(() => { logout(user) });
    });
  }
});
```

Another way is to define your callback functions then compose your tests for each user.

```
testCallback1 = function() {
  // test code with user
}

testCallback2 = function() {
  // test code with user
}

describe('test for user'), () => {
  let user = users[0];
  beforeAll(() => { login(user) });
  it('should do a test', testCallback1);
  it('should do another test', testCallback2);
  afterAll(() => { logout(user) });
});

describe('test for user'), () => {
  let user = users[1];
  beforeAll(() => { login(user) });
  it('should do a test', testCallback1);
  it('should do another test', testCallback2);
  afterAll(() => { logout(user) });
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this. These are just a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario and here is how I've tackled it. I added an array of users in the protractor config and then I can loop through those users to run my login tests. It's essentially the same setup as the first suggestion by cnishina in his answer. The difference for me is that my test code lives in one file and I have the code that gets the users and loops through them in another file. Probably overkill for a simple scenario but we have several different types of users (admin, non-admin, users with services, users without services, etc.) to run the login tests against so this helps to simplify that situation. I'm using TypeScript but the same thing can be done with JS if that's what you are using.

```
//in the protractor config
params: {
    loginUsers: [
        "login1@domain.test",
        "login2@domain.test",
        "login3@domain.test",
        //and so on ...
    ]
}
```

Then I have a file where my login tests live called `shared-login.tests.ts`

```
export default class SharedLoginTests {
    public static sharedSetup(url: string): void {
        beforeEach(() => {
           //shared setup code ... 
        }

        afterEach(() => {
            //shared tear down code ...
        }
    }

    public static executeSharedLoginTests(username: string): void {
        it(`should allow ${username} to login`, () => {
            //login test code ...
        }   
    }
}
```

And then I have `login.tests.ts` like this:

```
import { browser } from "protractor";
import SharedLoginTests from "./shared-login.tests";

describe(testtitle, () => {

    const users: string[] = browser.params.loginUsers;

    SharedLoginTests.sharedSetup(browser.params.baseUrl);

    for (const user of users) {
        SharedLoginTests.executeSharedLoginTests(user);
    }
});
```